# Betabinomial (BB) regression in the gamlss package (R)

Tags: beta-binomial-distribution, gamlss, archaeology

I'd be grateful for any help with beta-binomial (BB) regression in the gamlss package: predictions
from the fitted model of "mu" values for each observation in my data seem reasonable. But the
predictions for the "sigma" values do not.

```
exampleData <- structure(list(unit = c("F003", "F008", "F012A", "F018", "F12.SG13", 
                        "F12.SG14_16", "F12_NE_L01", "F12_NW_L01", "F12_NW_L03", "F12_SE_L01", 
                        "F12_SE_L02", "F12_SW_L01", "F12_SW_L03", "F12_SW_L04", "F12SE_L02A", 
                        "F12SE_L03A", "F12SEL033A", "F166", "F167"), 
               time = c(2.99166666666667, 
                        3.06666666666667, 3.26666666666667, 2.82, 2.88571428571429, 3.13, 
                        2.85652173913043, 2.91190476190476, 3.025, 2.89393939393939, 
                        2.9875, 2.81176470588235, 3.11, 2.92727272727273, 2.74444444444444, 
                        2.8625, 2.91, 2.94, 3.04), imported = c(58L, 20L, 13L, 10L, 24L, 
                                                                25L, 85L, 62L, 46L, 49L, 22L, 96L, 22L, 17L, 11L, 57L, 81L, 15L, 
                                                                6L), local = c(70L, 22L, 16L, 0L, 42L, 37L, 180L, 82L, 38L, 82L, 
                                                                               30L, 129L, 9L, 11L, 0L, 187L, 157L, 11L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                  -19L))
```

And here is a plot. The x axis is a measure of time. The y axis is the proportion
of imported vs. local ceramics in 19 archaeological assemblages, computed from counts in the dataframe.

[image: Here is a plot of the data:]

```
ggplot(exampleData,aes(x = time, y = imported/ (local+ imported))) +
  geom_point(shape=21,  fill='black', size=6)  +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label= unit), point.padding=1, cex=6) +
  labs(title= 'Proportion Imported vs. Time',
       x = '(Late)    Time     (Early)')
```

There's some theory that leads me to expect that as we go from right (early) to
left (late) on the plot, we should see increased variation among assemblages in
the proportion of imported ceramics. The data seem to fit that -- if you squint!
But a statistical model would be nice.

The BB seems like it might work: we  imagine the proportions (p) are drawn from the beta distribution, with the mean (mu) and SD (sigma) parameters changing over time. The observed counts follow binomial distributions, with parameter p drawn from a beta, with mu and sigma
for the given value of time.

I try to fit this using gamlss():

```
library(gamlss)

model1  <- gamlss(cbind(imported, local) ~ time ,
                  sigma.formula = ~ time,
                  family=BB(mu.link = "logit", sigma.link="log"),
                  data= exampleData) 
  
summary(model1)  

GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = 137.6181 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 132.5696 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 3: Global Deviance = 131.6102 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 4: Global Deviance = 131.4148 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 5: Global Deviance = 131.3634 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 6: Global Deviance = 131.3533 
GAMLSS-RS iteration 7: Global Deviance = 131.3535 
Warning messages:
1: In dBB(y, mu, sigma, bd, log = TRUE) :
   values of sigma in BB less that 1e-10 are set to 1e-10
2: In dBB(y, mu, sigma, bd, log = TRUE) :
   values of sigma in BB less that 1e-10 are set to 1e-10
3: In dBB(y, mu, sigma, bd, log = TRUE) :
   values of sigma in BB less that 1e-10 are set to 1e-10
4: In dBB(y, mu, sigma, bd, log = TRUE) :
   values of sigma in BB less that 1e-10 are set to 1e-10
5: In dBB(y, mu, sigma, bd, log = TRUE) :
   values of sigma in BB less that 1e-10 are set to 1e-10
>   
> summary(model1)  
******************************************************************
Family:  c("BB", "Beta Binomial") 

Call:  gamlss(formula = cbind(imported, local) ~ time, sigma.formula = ~time,      family = BB(mu.link = "logit", sigma.link = "log"),  
    data = exampleData) 

Fitting method: RS() 

------------------------------------------------------------------
Mu link function:  logit
Mu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -2.7035     3.4224  -0.790    0.442
time          0.8619     1.1245   0.767    0.455

------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  log
Sigma Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   127.37      52.35   2.433   0.0280 *
time          -45.17      18.37  -2.459   0.0266 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  19 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  4
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  15 
                      at cycle:  7 
 
Global Deviance:     131.3535 
            AIC:     139.3535 
            SBC:     143.1313 
******************************************************************
```

The warnings are worrisome. And it looks like there is reason to worry. When I extract the fitted values for mu, the results looks reasonable.

```
fitted(model1, parameter='mu' )
 [1] 0.4688241 0.4849496 0.5280128 0.4322119 0.4461619 0.4985925 0.4399530 0.4517467 0.4759850 0.4479145 0.4679299 0.4304708
[13] 0.4942830 0.4550295 0.4163059 0.4412231 0.4513401 0.4577512 0.4792108
```

But not for sigma:

```
fitted(model1, parameter='sigma' )
           1            2            3            4            5            6            7            8            9           10 
3.912561e-04 1.278633e-05 1.395848e-09 9.842343e-01 4.912797e-02 7.114456e-07 1.860457e-01 1.487673e-02 8.553487e-05 3.375929e-02 
          11           12           13           14           15           16           17           18           19 
4.731522e-04 1.432966e+00 1.771464e-06 7.380322e-03 3.089009e+01 1.416423e-01 1.622707e-02 4.130037e-03 4.315192e-05
```

Note the sigma estimate for observation 15 = 30.  This is impossible, since sigma must range between 0 and 1, given the parameterization of the beta that gamlss uses. And most of the other estimates seem way too small: close to 0, which is what the warnings seem to be about.

If I try to back up and simplfy by estimate and intercepts-only model, I get this:

```
model2  <- gamlss(cbind(imported, local) ~ 1 ,
                  sigma.formula = ~ 1,
                  family=BB(mu.link = "logit", sigma.link="log"),
                  data= exampleData) 
  
summary(model2) 
******************************************************************
Family:  c("BB", "Beta Binomial") 

Call:  gamlss(formula = cbind(imported, local) ~ 1, sigma.formula = ~1,      family = BB(mu.link = "logit", sigma.link = "log"),      data = exampleData) 

Fitting method: RS() 

------------------------------------------------------------------
Mu link function:  logit
Mu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.002728   0.182349   0.015    0.988

------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  log
Sigma Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  -2.1158     0.5438  -3.891  0.00117 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  19 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  2
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  17 
                      at cycle:  5 
 
Global Deviance:     147.3811 
            AIC:     151.3811 
            SBC:     153.2699 
******************************************************************
```

No warnings.  But when I plot the beta distribution from these parameter estimates,
the resulting pdf looks way to narrow to accommodate the data on the scatter plot.

```
muPred  <- exp(0.002728)/(1+exp( 0.002728))
sigmaPred <- exp(-2.1158)
p <- seq(.01, .99, .01)
plot(p, dBE(p, muPred, sigmaPred) )
```

[image]

This is my first time out with this kind of thing, so I am unsure if the problem is my
understanding of the BB model, my code, a mismatch beteeen the data and the model, or
something else.

Thank you for any suggestions about how to proceed.

Best, Fraser

Comment: At first glance: Your final graph depicts a beta distribution, yet you fitted a beta-binomial distribution `BB`. So you should probably replace `dBE` with `dBB`.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see exactly what is going on without
the data counts.

However in the Y ~ BB(n,mu,sigma) distribution model,
Y|p ~ BI(n,p)
where I believe
p ~ BE(mu, [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5).

[Note that sigma lies between 0 and infinity,
while [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5 lies between 0 and 1.]

So in your intercept model,
p ~ BE(0.501,0.328)
which may be more reasonable.

For your model with time as explanatory variable:

Note that as sigma → 0, then BB(mu, sigma,nu) → BI(n,mu).

So for those time points with a very small fitted sigma,
this suggests that a BI(n,mu) distribution model for the response variable is adequate
[rather than a BB(mu, sigma,nu) distribution model, which is
an over-dispersed BI(n,mu) distribution].

This seems a very reasonable conclusion to me
(although I agree that the very small sigmas look odd at first sight).

I think the warning messages are just warning you that some of the fitted sigmas are very low.

I suggest that you plot the fitted mu against time,
the fitted sigma against time,
and the fitted [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5 against time.

If you still have problems, post them,
or email the developers of gamlss directly
ideally with the data counts.

Comment: Thanks Robert! Very helpful. Do you have a citation for "I believe p ~ BE(mu, [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5)"?  I can't find any indication in the gamlss documentation that the _sigma_  estimate from the BB family can be used to estimate the dispersion parameter of the BE() function as [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5. Thanks!!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.

Answer (score 0):

The citation is by combining
pages 523 and 461 of

‘Distributions for Modeling Location, Scale, and Shape: Using GAMLSS in R’  R. A. Rigby, M. D. Stasinopoulos, G. Z. Heller and F. De Bastiani.
Chapman and Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, 2019

Page 523 says if Y ~ BB(n, mu, sigma), then
Y|p ~ BI(n,p) where
p ~ BEo(mu/sigma, [1-mu]/sigma)

i.e. p ~ BEo(a, b)
where a=mu/sigma and b = [1-mu]/sigma.

Page 461 says
BEo(a, b) = BE(mu_1,sigma_1)
where  mu_1 = a/(a+b)
and  sigma_1 = (a+b+1)^(-0.5).

So  mu_1 = mu
and sigma_1 = [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5.

So in conclusion if

Y ~ BB(n, mu, sigma), then

Y|p ~ BI(n,p) where
p ~ BE(mu, [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5).

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to Robert for the help! https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/331864/robert

I took his advice and emailed the authors of gamlss in hopes with help about the warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In dBB(y, mu, sigma, bd, log = TRUE) :
   values of sigma in BB less that 1e-10 are set to 1e-10
```

No replies.

However a kludge that seems to solve he problem and produce reasonable parameter estimates is to add 1 to the pairs of counts in the logit we are trying to predict. The warnings go away:

```
> > model1  <- gamlss(cbind(imported +1, local+1) ~ time ,
> +                   sigma.formula = ~ time,
> +                   family=BB(mu.link = "logit", sigma.link="log"),
> +                   data= exampleData) GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = 137.1545  GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 134.6811
> GAMLSS-RS iteration 3: Global Deviance = 134.3208  GAMLSS-RS iteration
> 4: Global Deviance = 134.2792  GAMLSS-RS iteration 5: Global Deviance
> = 134.2711  GAMLSS-RS iteration 6: Global Deviance = 134.2703 
> > summary(model1)
> ****************************************************************** Family:  c("BB", "Beta Binomial") 
> 
> Call:  gamlss(formula = cbind(imported + 1, local + 1) ~ time,  
>     sigma.formula = ~time, family = BB(mu.link = "logit",  
>         sigma.link = "log"), data = exampleData) 
> 
> Fitting method: RS() 
> 
> ------------------------------------------------------------------ Mu link function:  logit Mu Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) (Intercept)  -2.7322     2.9540  -0.925    0.370 time          0.8718     0.9741   0.895    0.385
> 
> ------------------------------------------------------------------ Sigma link function:  log Sigma Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   (Intercept)    73.29      29.70   2.468   0.0261 * time          -26.47      10.46  -2.531   0.0231 *
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> ------------------------------------------------------------------ No. of observations in the fit:  19  Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  4
>       Residual Deg. of Freedom:  15 
>                       at cycle:  6    Global Deviance:     134.2703 
>             AIC:     142.2703 
>             SBC:     146.0481 
> ******************************************************************
```

As Robert writes, the predicted values for sigma (the dispersion parameter) produced by the gamlss function can be used to compute the sigma parameter of the beta distribution as parameterized in the function gamlss::rBE() as follows:

```
sigma_BE = (sigma/(1+sigma))^0.5
```

And I managed to demonstrate that to myself with the following code:

```
    > theta <- rBE(n=1000, mu=.5, sigma=.2)
    > N <- rep(50, 1000)
    > x<- rbinom(n=rep(1,1000), size= N, prob=theta)
    > 
    > 
    > model2 <- gamlss(cbind(x,N-x)~1,
    +     sigma.formula = ~ 1,
    +     family=BB(mu.link = "logit", sigma.link="log"))
    GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = 6442.315 
    GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 6441.646 
    GAMLSS-RS iteration 3: Global Deviance = 6441.646 
    > summary(model3)
    ******************************************************************
    Family:  c("BB", "Beta Binomial") 
    
    Call:  gamlss(formula = cbind(x, N - x) ~ 1, sigma.formula = ~1,  
        family = BB(mu.link = "logit", sigma.link = "log")) 
    
    Fitting method: RS() 
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mu link function:  logit
    Mu Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept) -0.01037    0.01556  -0.666    0.505
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    Sigma link function:  log
    Sigma Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept) -3.14238    0.06521  -48.19   <2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    No. of observations in the fit:  1000 
    Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  2
          Residual Deg. of Freedom:  998 
                          at cycle:  3 
     
    Global Deviance:     6467.537 
                AIC:     6471.537 
                SBC:     6481.353 
    ******************************************************************
    > sigma <- exp(coef(model2, parameter='sigma' ))
    > sigma
    (Intercept) 
     0.04138326 
    > sigma_BE <- (sigma/(1+sigma))^0.5 
    > sigma_BE
    (Intercept) 
  0.1993458
```

Thanks again!

Best, Fraser

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about the warnings,
as they are just telling you that the fitted sigma is close to zero.

I would plot the fitted mu against time,
the fitted sigma against time,
and the fitted [sigma/(1+sigma)]^0.5 against time,
and see if the plots look reasonable.

Also I do not think you should add 1 to the pairs of counts in the logit as this is (slightly) distorting the data,
and so is sub-optimal.